# Downloading data from App Engine, not getting all entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Following [the guide here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html), I'm trying to download data from my App Engine datastore.

I'm using the command:

```
download_data --application=myapp --kind=Rating --url=http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename="C:\Users\data.dump"
```

And I get the output:

```
Downloading data records.

[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20110121.171839
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20110121.171839.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20110121.171839.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
[INFO    ] Downloading kinds: ['Rating']
.[INFO    ] Have 9 entities, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 9 entities (1860706 bytes) transferred in 5.7 seconds

FINISHED
```

Which seems fine except I have almost 200 entities in the datastore, not 9 as seems to be the case here. What am I missing? Is there a way to force it to download all the entities or am I just missing a command line option in there?

Comment: Are all of those 200 entities in the 'Rating' table?

Comment: Yes - altogether there are 249,304 entities, but only 200 of the type 'Rating'. I only want those.

Comment: out of curiosity, what's your app id? (don't worry, it's not confidential or sensitive, and no one can do anything malicious with it.)

Comment: also: do all 200 Rating entities show up in the admin console data viewer? which version of the SDK are you using the bulk loader from? do you have any indexes in states other than Serving? (that shouldn't actually matter, but i'm still curious.)

Comment: My app id is "astronomypictureoftheday" - I'm using it as the backing to an Android app. All the entities show up in the viewer, it's the latest SDK 1.4.1, all my indexes are serving. The entities themselves do vary, though, as I've added extra attributes as time has gone on and not updated the old. Any insight you have is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

given all the information in the comments, i have to guess this is either a bulk loader bug or a problem with your app's data or indices.

if it's the latter, two things you can try are 1) re-`put()` all of the Rating entities, and 2) remove and recreate the indices that the bulk loader uses, e.g. the `__key__` descending index.

if neither of those works, post on the [group](http://code.google.com/appengine/forum/) or go to the [IRC office hours](http://code.google.com/appengine/community.html) (scroll down) and ask a team member to take a look.